# Prove that $e^{A}= e(I+2B+2B^{2})$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following statement but I don't know how we can get there:

We have square matrix ( same size ) $A,I,B$ such that $A = I + 2B$ , (I is the identity) and $B$ is a nilpotent matrix such that $B^{3}=0$

Then we have :

$$e^{A}= e(I+2B+2B^{2})$$

I used the formula $e^{X+Y}=e^{X}e^{Y}$ if $XY=YX$

But it doesn't lead me anywhere, so if you guys can help. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's done sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If $A = I+2B$, $e^A = e e^{2B}$.  Now use the Maclaurin series of $\exp$, truncating after the $B^2$ term.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Using your formula, we have $e^A = e^Ie^{2B}$. Compute $e^{2B}$ by using the power series definition of $e^X$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
e^{I+2B} = e^I * e^{2B}\\
= e^I * (I + 2B + 2B^2 +0)\\
$$